# Mysql TINYINT & VARCHAR performance

Tags: mysql

I have a column build in mysql db, it store the value - 10000 in `TINYINT`, what if I change it to 10k `VARCHAR` which one will be better performance?

ex. 10000, 20000, 30000.... or 10k, 20k, 30k...

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just selecting the value then it doesn't matter.

But if you are using it in a where condition then the performance will be better using an `int`. Example:

```
select * from your_table
where your_column > 1000
```

will only work if the column is an `int` and you don't need to convert it back to a number.

Generally - if it is a number - store it as number.

Comment: varchar will be 10k VARCHAR(3), 10000 TINYINT(5), will this matter

Comment: `tinyint(5)` is a small int from `0` to `255`. `varchar(3)` has 3 or more bytes. varchar needs more space anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger question is -- would it help your project? With `TINYINT` you can perform math operations on it. You can't do that with `VARCHAR`, since your numbers would be a string. Sure you could manipulate the string into a number, but that'll cost you in performance as well as the need to make extra code (which can unnecessarily complicate the SQL or other language).

*If you're going to make a value be a number -- then by all means make it an integer*. There's a reason really really smart people made a difference between string's & int's.